# Samsung Galaxy s2 AVD (MAC)

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device

I have downloaded the Skin from Samsungs website for the Samsung Galaxy S2 from here:[Samsung Galaxy S2 Skin](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9576&listReturnUrl=http://innovator.samsungmobile.com:80/platform.main.do?platformId=1&indexType=1&indexDirection=1&sortType=0&cateId=1&codeType=C512&tabNum=1&searchText=&curPage=2&listLines=&linkType=0&nacode=&codeType=C512)

It instructs to unzip the file into the add-ons directory under the SDK area - well I have done this but the Skin does not appear within a new AVD no matter what version of Android I choose. I have even unzipped the file into the platforms directory and even unzipped it under platforms/android-10/skins as well.

Any ideas on this as I am using an Apple Mac so I do not know whether this Skin is meant to work with all O/S's

Comment: -1 Off topic. Belongs on Super User

Comment: Perfectly valid question about the Android SDK and the emulator. I have wondered the emulator skin issue in Ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 2):

If the target version you selected in the AVD is API level 10, you need to do the following to make it show up in the built-in skins.

- Go to the directory where you unzipped the skin ([Android-SDK directory]/platforms/android-10/skins)
- Edit the manifest.ini
- Change api=9 to api=10

Then it should show up.